# Widget in HeatMap with Holoviews

Tags: widget, heatmap, holoviews

I want add a widget in my HeatMap with Holoviews. 
 For istance, I have:
z, a, b = np.histogram2d(df['a'], df['b'])
hv.Image((a, b, z), ['a', 'b'], 'Count')

and I want a widget that let me change a third variable (like "Symbol" in the follow example: http://holoviews.org/user_guide/Dashboards.html )

This is my HeatMap: 
z, a, b = np.histogram2d(data['X'],data['Y'])
hv.Image((a, b, z), ['X', 'Y'], 'Count')

And I would do something like the follow but with the prewious plot (the HeatMap):

ds = hv.Dataset(data, kdims=['X', 'Y'], vdims=['Z'])
ds.to(hv.Curve, kdims=['X'], vdims=['Y'], groupby=['Z'])

Comment: Try looking up HoloMap in the HoloViews docs; maybe you'll be able to answer your own question (and if so please add it here).

Comment: I tried but I can't anyway

Comment: In that case I can give an example, but I'd need runnable code to start with.

Comment: z, a, b = np.histogram2d(data['X'],data['Y']) hv.Image((a, b, z), ['X', 'Y'], 'Count')

and I would add the widget for the variable 'Z'

Answer (score 0):

```
z, a, b = np.histogram2d(data['X'],data['Y'])
hv.Image((a, b, z), ['X', 'Y'], 'Count')
```

and I would add the widget for the variable `'Z'`